# How to inspect the Javascript setTimeout queue?

Tags: javascript

I have a very complex JS application that queues a lot of logic to be executed when possible via setTimeout(). This is necessary to prevent slow script warnings in IE7/8.

I know. I wish I didn't have to support these either.

Anyhow, I need to know when all of these operations are finished so I can unlock the UI for the user.

Is there a way to inspect the JS task queue?

Comment: "Inspect" by means of debugging, or "inspect" by means of programmatic access to check whether there are outstanding timeouts? If the latter, then the answer is **No**, and it's a bad idea anyway.

Comment: Inspect as in programmatic access. Not certain how read-only access to that would be a bad idea.

Comment: `setTimeout` is a global functionality. What if some completely unrelated module would schedule a function in 24 hours? How do you know that *your* tasks have finished by looking at the queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep a count of how many chunks you've started and have each chunk decrement that count, check whether it's zero, and if so run your completion logic.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that and may have to do that. I'm sort of curious at this point, though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that in any browser.

But you can use the [Promise pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) to notify someone when an asynchronous operation completes.

Here is an simplistic example using [jQuery's promise implementation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/), using `setTimeout` to breakup execution so the user won't be warned about scripts that take too long to execute:

```
// a factory for promises
function createPromiseFor(doWork) {
    // create a deferred object
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    // a function that will schedule our work;
    function scheduleMoreWork() {
        setTimeout(function () {

            // doWork does at least some of the work, and tells us when it is done
            var finished = doWork();

            if (finished) {
                deferred.resolve();
            } else {
                scheduleMoreWork();
            }
        }, 1);
    };

    // schedule the first one
    scheduleMoreWork();

    return deferred.promise();
}

// assuming ourFunction does its work in chunks and can resume from where it left off...
var promise = createPromiseFor(ourFunction);
promise.done(function () {
    alert('done!');
});
```

And here is an example of a function which can pause itself, and resumes the next time it is called:

```
var fn = (function () {
    var goal = 100,
        iterationsPerInvocation = 10,
        current = 0;

    function invoke() {
        for (var i = 0; i < iterationsPerInvocation; ++i) {
            current++;
        }
    }

    return function () {
        invoke();
        return current === goal;
    }
})();

var promise = createPromiseFor(fn);
promise.done(function () {
    alert('done!');
});
```

Comment: You're not even calling `scheduleMoreWork`? Btw, that's not the "promise pattern", that's just abusing deferreds as an event observer.

Comment: Thank you, I added the initial call to `scheduleMoreWork`.  And this *is* promise pattern; we have subscribed a callback to be notified upon completion of some activity; it doesn't matter what that activity is.

Comment: For example, jQuery uses promises to notify you when an AJAX request completes.  Under the hood, the browser is most likely polling while reading the data from network.

Comment: Hm, I call that pub/sub. To me, "the" [promise pattern](http://domenic.me/2012/10/14/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/) is chaining them, which should be done here instead of simply nesting the `setTimeout`s.

Comment: The OP has to use `setTimeout`, otherwise the browser will nag the user about slow script execution.  jQuery deferreds/promises don't asynchronous execute things

Comment: I didn't say anything against `setTimeout`, I just wanted to *chain* them.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, guys. I'm using $q in angular a lot but hadn't thought of resolving my deferred in the timeout. I ended up going with the simpler answer above because I have so many deferred operations that keeping track of them via scope-level variable is easier.

Answer (score 1):

Realize this is a very dated thread, but ran into a similar need to queue tasks, with the option to clear redundant tasks in the javascript setTimeout queue, as the process queue begins emptying...

Essentially wrapped the setTimeout and clearTimeout functions to track the setTimeout process queue using a Map (named setTimeoutQueue).  (This function wrapping technique isn't anything new, as I've seen it employed with custom event handler mixins, which preempt and postempt(?) methods of objects or classes.)  The core concept being that as the processes pop off the queue, the active process can search setTimeoutQueue to determine if redundant tasks are sitting in the queue, and if so, use the preempted clearTimeout function to clear both the actual queued process and the corresponding task entry tracked by setTimeoutQueue.

```
const actualSetTimeout = setTimeout;
const actualClearTimeout = clearTimeout;

setTimeoutQueue = new Map();

setTimeout = function(f, ms, ...fArgs) {

  console.log(`setTimeout "${f}" - BEFORE QUEUING TASK.`);
  console.log(setTimeoutQueue);

  const setTimeoutHandle = actualSetTimeout(
    function() {
      console.log(`setTimeout "${f}" - BEFORE EXECUTION.`);
      console.log(setTimeoutQueue);

      const fResult = f(...fArgs);
      setTimeoutQueue.delete(setTimeoutHandle);

      console.log(`setTimeout "${f}" - AFTER EXECUTION.`);
      console.log(setTimeoutQueue);
      return fResult;
    },
    ms,
    ...fArgs
  );

  setTimeoutQueue.set(setTimeoutHandle, [f, ms, ...fArgs]);

  console.log(`setTimeout "${f}" - AFTER QUEUING TASK.`);
  console.log(setTimeoutQueue);

  return setTimeoutHandle;
}

clearTimeout = function(id) {
  actualClearTimeout(id);
  setTimeoutQueue.delete(id);
}

console.log(setTimeoutQueue);
setTimeout((...args)=>{console.log(`5 sec timer fired with params = ${args}`)}, 5000, 555, 5555);
setTimeout((x)=>{console.log(`2 sec timer fired with first param = ${x}`)}, 2000, 222);
setTimeout(()=>{console.log(`Queued for immediate execution.`)});
console.log(setTimeoutQueue);
```

Obviously all the "console.logs" are there to assist in understanding the execution sequence, in addition to denoting custom code injection points.  Only uncertainty I have is any side effects of preempting the setTimeout and clearTimeout functions, but time and constructive criticism will tell... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There used to be several tools for inspecting running intervals; such as:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/setinterval-sniffer/odkgihncjgklajjabihpoipfnpcjhdno/related?hl=en

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/timeouts-and-intervals/oagmfffelnnohpbidjknmhfangoahcan

But it appears these don't work anymore. If anyone knows of a way of seeing these in Chrome (or FireFox / Edge) Developer Tools, please comment.